# How to make a cover image fit for mobile devices?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image-processing

I'm currently designing a website and am not sure what to do about the size of the cover image when displayed on mobile. Aka it's looking huge at the moment on mobile, and I had like to make it fit for mobile devices.

The (perfectly working) code for desktop:

```
#cover {
    background: url('...') 50% 0 repeat-y fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For mobile, I added the following (different sections for 980, 768 and 760):

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {

    #cover {
        height: 65vh;
        background: url('');
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

But it's still not showing properly on mobile devices (the same size as desktop size literally). Should I add anything in the @media code in terms of fixed and centered position, or add more code in relation to the exact dimensions? I have tried a lot already, but I'm a bit stuck... Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: I've found that `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover` don't always work nicely. Anything `fixed` seems to assume that it's size is the entire viewport, and it resizes to fit that, NOT the size given to the element. The only workaround if you really want both `fixed` and `cover` is to calculate the covering size yourself and set it with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the first line :

```
background: url('...') 50% 0 repeat-y fixed;
```

This is a one-line shorthand for :

```
background-image : url('...');
background-position-x : 50%;
background-position-y : 0;
background-repeat : repeat-y;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

`background-attachment: fixed` is the problem. If you remove it, it works and the image is centered :

```css
#cover {
    background : url(http://via.placeholder.com/800x600) 50% 0 repeat-y;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    border: blue dashed 2px;
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {

    #cover {
        height: 65vh;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: red dashed 2px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="cover"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! I tried to add the above code, it seems to work when I 'crop' the desktop screen, however once displayed on my iPad or mobile two images appear. One still very much enlarged image is directly visible on the screen, and it seems like an extra image - with the correct dimensions - is placed on top of the main and directly visible image. This one is only visible when 'scrolling' the screen upwards. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Well yes, you explicitely ask the image to repeat by using `repeat-y`. If you don't want it to repeat, use `none`.